# Telerik radgrid pagination issue - next page, prev page, first page and last page not working

Tags: vb.net, telerik-grid

I have tried everything I could possibly gather from what I read (from adding a need source to adding pageindexchanged, etc., but still am not able to figure it out... any assistance would be gratefully lapped up...

following is my code...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="ram1" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ajaxtimer1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rgNewsFeed" LoadingPanelID="LoadingPanel1" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>

    <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="LoadingPanel1" runat="server" />

      <telerik:RadGrid ID="rg1" runat="server" ShowStatusBar="True" AllowPaging="true" >
         <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" TableLayout="Fixed">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CommentSubject" HeaderText="Subject" />
                <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn DataTextField="CommentText" DataTextFormatString="{0}" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Views/m.aspx?pEntityID={0}" 
                    DataNavigateUrlFields="CmtTextID" HeaderText="Details" UniqueName="gbcCommentText" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="EntityFundName" HeaderText="Entity/Fund" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="EnteredBy" HeaderText="Entered by" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CommentAge" HeaderText="Last Updated" />
            </Columns>
         </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3000">
        </asp:Timer>
    </asp:Panel>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind

```
Protected Sub OnLoad(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        rg1.DataSource = dt 'some datatable
        rg1.DataBind()

End Sub

Public Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        rg1.DataSource = dt 'some datatable
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
End Sub

Protected Sub rgLeoNotesNewsFeed_NeedDataSource(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs) Handles rgLeoNotesNewsFeed.NeedDataSource


    rg1.DataSource = dt 'some datatable


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'd replace `asp:UpdatePanel` with `telerik:RadAjaxPanel`. I had to use telerik components for a while and did not have the best time. If you're using radgrid and aiming to use updatepanel with it, use a corresponding telerik component such as `telerik:RadAjaxPanel`. This way you will experience less issues.

Second, I'm a bit confused with the following part

```
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ajaxtimer1">
    <UpdatedControls>
        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rgNewsFeed" LoadingPanelID="LoadingPanel1" />
    </UpdatedControls>
</telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

You don't seem to have any controls with the IDs `rgNewsFeed` and `ajaxtimer1`. You're basically saying **RadAjaxManager** to update **rgNewsFeed** on **ajaxtimer1** update.

Shouldn't this be like

```
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="Timer1">
    <UpdatedControls>
        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rg1" LoadingPanelID="LoadingPanel1" />
    </UpdatedControls>
</telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

Also, you need to ajaxify your grid like that

```
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rg1">
    <UpdatedControls>
        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rg1"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
    </UpdatedControls>
</telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

Not sure if your issue is related to those, but give it a try and see if that works.

**EDIT**

```
Protected Sub OnLoad(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        rg1.DataSource = dt 'some datatable
        rg1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

I think you should set the datasource on each call but call `DataBind` method only if it's not a postback. Try the following.

```
Protected Sub OnLoad(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    rg1.DataSource = dt 'some datatable
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        rg1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In my bid to obfuscate, I went overboard. Sorry for the obvious errors in code... I will try to implement your suggestions and get back to you.

Comment: Actually, not binding on postback did the trick... thanks much!